# Slow mysql connection to remote DB

Tags: mysql, apache, amazon-web-services

Here's my scenario:  I have a LAMP server hosted through Amazon AWS that is hosted in the US East region.  That web server connects to a local mysql DB and everything runs quickly and smoothly.  I recently installed Apache on my computer so I can develop locally and set it up to connect to the DB on the live server instead of setting up a database locally.

The problem is, the requests from my local machine to the DB server are slow.  I tested 5 queries selecting a limit of 1, 10, 100, 1000, and 10000 from a random table.  Here are my results:

**Production server connecting locally:**

```
Total time : 0.1961 seconds
Connection : 0.069 seconds
Query Limit 1 : 0.0001 seconds
Query Limit 10 : 0.0001 seconds
Query Limit 100 : 0.0003 seconds
Query Limit 1000 : 0.002 seconds
Query Limit 10000 : 0.1246 seconds
```

**My comp connecting remotely:**

```
Total time : 8.2012 seconds
Connection : 0.813 seconds
Query Limit 1 : 0.2133 seconds
Query Limit 10 : 0.3243 seconds
Query Limit 100 : 0.8209 seconds
Query Limit 1000 : 1.2209 seconds
Query Limit 10000 : 4.8088 seconds
```

**Here are my ping results to said server:**

```
Reply from xx.xx.xx.xxx: bytes=32 time=117ms TTL=42
Reply from xx.xx.xx.xxx: bytes=32 time=120ms TTL=42
Reply from xx.xx.xx.xxx: bytes=32 time=126ms TTL=42
Reply from xx.xx.xx.xxx: bytes=32 time=116ms TTL=42

Ping statistics for xx.xx.xx.xxx:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 116ms, Maximum = 126ms, Average = 119ms
```

**And here's the table description:**

```
col1    mediumint(9)    unsigned NO    PRI    NULL    auto_increment
col2    varchar(128)             YES          NULL
col3    varchar(100)             NO    MUL    NULL  
col4    mediumtext               YES   MUL    NULL  
col5    tinyint(1)               YES   MUL    0
```

I know about the skip_name_resolve mysql variable and have set it to ON, but I didn't see any improvements.  Is this simply a latency/data transfer issue between my comp (US West Coast) to the DB server?  Ideally I'd like to continue working with the remote db, but should I just work with a local copy of the DB instead?

Comment: You havent told us how much data each row is. This could very well just be a network latency if you are selecting out a large amount of columns or columns that have large values.

Comment: Edited my question to include the table description

Comment: But still we dont know how much data there is. "mediumtext" can store an awful lot of data (I forget off hand). Knowing the schema alone doesnt answer the question "how much data are you transferring across the wire"

Comment: Average row length of this particular table is 805 bytes.  If you switch from `select *` to `select col1` (which is the mediumint) the `limit 1` query is still taking ~0.12 seconds, whereas it takes ~.0001 seconds from the localhost

Comment: Yeah I would second the data size idea. The times are not especially slow until you get to the larger number of rows.

Comment: The problem is optimized queries are taking about 1/8th of a second when I'm expecting them to take about 1/10,000th.  When accessing a page with something like 40 queries it'll take 5+ seconds to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but it's still probably relevant for some people. It turns out that this was simply a data transfer/latency issue. The latency from the queries on the local web server to the remote DB (across the country) were simply adding up. I decided to connect to a local DB for development and everything was much quicker.